# ElasticSearch Nest SortGeoDistance

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to use SortGeoDistance in query results from Nest client for ElasticSearch. Can someone please give me an example how to use it since I can't find any in documentation.

Answer (score 3):

This unit tests shows an example usage:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/1.x/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Search/Sorting/SortTests.cs#L175

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Search/Sorting/SortTests.cs#L175